How to increase SignalR Timeout
I'm running a WebAPI project using Visual Studio 2022 and .net9.  I also have a Blazor Web App which uses the API. There is a SignalR connection between the two. I keep getting timed out while stepping through code in 15 seconds.  I've tried a few things I got from here, but no luck.
I have this in the API
builder.Services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
{
  hubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
  hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
  hubOptions.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
});

and this on the Blazor app
hubConnection.ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

After 15 seconds, sometimes I get this:
'The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.'
How can I increase the timeout?
Thank you.
